# How can I load s3 object with mmap in Python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can mmap local binary files like the sample code below, but what about the binary files on s3 (i.e., what if the test.p file is in a s3 bucket)?
Anybody has a hint? Thanks!

```
import pickle
import mmap

# Create a test list and serialize it 
test = ['a', 'b']
with open('./test.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(test, f)

# memory map the serialized file    
with open('./test.p', 'rb') as f:
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

# read the mmap object like a local file
test = pickle.load(m)
print test
```

Comment: Please, add some code showing what you have already tried!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just added what I have tried.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Noeda/mmapurl) project seems to accomplish this using the userfaultfd syscall.